# Predetermined name roulette for raffle

Tags: javascript, arrays, selector, picker, roulette-wheel-selection

I want to design a name roulette using Javascript for an upcoming raffle we're hosting.

Similar to [this.](https://primaryschoolict.com/random-name-selector/)

We're planning to draw the names before the event to save time. However, we want to preserve the tension and excitement by displaying it in a roulette. How do I go about fixing the draw? Any suggestions or any resources you can share?

Thanks!

Comment: So create a loop and stop on the item....